# startActivityForResult and replacing child activity

Tags: java, android

I have three activities, ActivityA, ActivityB and ActivityC.

As the code is today, ActivityA will start ActivityB using startActivityForResult() and will receive return codes from ActivityB. No problem.

I have another Android activity, ActivityC, that represents an alternate way to generate the return code for ActivityA.

My question is this:

**Is it possible for ActivityB to create ActivityC in such a way that when ActivityC returns the onActivityResult() method in ActivityA is called?**

I am asking because I recall doing this in some Android project a year ago, however I cannot remember which one and Google wasn't giving me any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created 3 activities. Activity A started activity B for result and in turn activity B simply started activity C and called finish() on self. Activity C after launch, set the result to whatever A wanted nad called finish on self. onActivityResult in activity A was called, so I believe the answer is YES, it can be done.

Here are my sample activities
**Activity A:**

```
public class MainTestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_test);

        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent in = new Intent(MainTestActivity.this, TestActivityB.class);
                startActivityForResult(in, 101);
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_test, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Got Intent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

**Activity B:**

```
public class TestActivityB extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_test);

        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent in = new Intent(TestActivityB.this, TestActivityC.class);
                startActivity(in);
                finish();
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_test, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Activity C:**

```
public class TestActivityC extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_test);

        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                setResult(101);
                finish();
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_test, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I even commented the `finish()` in Activity B. Activity A was able to show the toast when I destroyed activity B by pressing the back button.

Comment: Was not what I wanted to do, but it does work. Great answer, thanks.